# Visualize feature class with many relationship classes?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, spatial-database

I have a feature class in a geodatabase that I want to review.

It has many relationship classes - possibly a hundred or more.  If I load the feature class into ArcMap and identify one of the features, it takes several minutes to expand the relations.

What is a good way to visualize this feature class so that I can understand it?  Specifically, I want to know if having a relation to a relation will obstruct editing the feature class.

Comment: So is the performance of the "Identify" and Edit tools the main issue here?

Comment: Not really, the issue was that I couldn't figure out what I was dealing with.  The performance of Identify is acceptable, the errors when editing are not.  I have contacted ESRI support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using the [ArcGIS Diagrammer](http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2010/07/arcgis-diagrammer-for-arcgis-10.html)?

Comment: I have not, but I will.  Thanks!

Comment: ArcGIS Diagrammer is the tool I was imagining - unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem (but it did help understand the dataset).

Answer (score 2):

You've probably put this one to bed, but I'll chip in anyway for future searchers.

ESRI has another tool similar to the ArcGIS diagrammer called the "Geodatabase diagrammer". This is the tool that they use internally to generate those pretty object diagrams in the ESRI press books.

The tool is available via ArcScripts. Note that you need Visio in order to view the tools output.

Comment: are you talking about geodatabase designer 2?

Comment: Nope, the tool is called Geodatabase Diagrammer for ArcGIS 9  http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=13616

Comment: Here's the link for Geodatabase Diagrammer for ArcGIS 10: http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geodatabase/details?entryID=951E03C6-1422-2418-345D-078CCC1C00CE